# Exporting the kinect-processing application

Tags: kinect, processing, simple-openni

Recently , I have created a sketch in Processing-1.5.1 using SimpleOpenNI-1.96 library. A sketch is running fine even on a present mode. But after export a sketch, it gives me a blank gray screen, also kinect's red light doen't respond, even running it from command line, it doesn't notify any error...  I only get a blank screen without stop button.

I am working on Windows System 64bit-OS with Processing-1.5.1 (framework) , SimpleOpenNI-1.96 library, Microsoft kinect xbox 360.

I don't know how to fix it.
Need your valuable help...

Thank you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried to use the newest version of processing ? 
in some case, Processing-1.5.1 is not suitable with SimpleOpenNI-1.96

Comment: Hello Faiz, I jump from windows to mac, and currently I can run kinect on mac through libfreenect. kinect sketches of Prcocessing library SimpleOpenNI-1.96 does not run. But from this site http://medienlabor.hs-osnabrueck.de/download/SimpleOpenNI_1.96_osx_kinect_1473.zip I have downloaded this library and its examples runs with Processing 2.1 and Processsing-2.0.3 (But not with Processing -1.5.1)..